# DataGridview with multiple information in same columns

Tags: c#, combobox, datagridviewcolumn

I have Database query result, which bind to DataGridView control.
Result would be like in c#.

```
    Column id(hidden in display)    Description        amount.**
           1                          abc             9/8/7/6/5/4/3/2  (depend on query) non selectable option
           2                          cdesd           1 or 0 (Check box would be great)
           3                          dekskd          1 or 0 (Check box would be great)
           4                          gkekskd         0/1/2/3/4  combo-box with selection option
```

I searched many article. I couldn't find it.
I would really appreciate if anyone help me out in this

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: What is the issue? Explain it in detail.

Comment: no Alex, I stil couldn't find final resolution but I m moving appropriate control in cell.

Comment: Are you trying to get different cell types (text, combo, check box) based on the data currently in the row?

Answer (score 2):

I would hook into the CellFormatting event.  You can do custom formatting for that specific cell.

[MSDN DataGridView.CellFormatting Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx)